# CNOT Gate in Pauli Basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

The CNOT gate is usually written as

> $|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I + |1\rangle\langle1|\otimes X$

(with $X,Y,Z$ beign the Pauli Basis and $I$ the Identity).

I have yet to stumble across the representation [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate) gives when looking at books on the topic:

> $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}\left(I-Z\right)\otimes\left(I-X\right)}$

How can I show these forms are equivalent?  Where can I find a derivation that shows this?

---

[Cross-posted on qc.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/26455/55)

Comment: Maybe ask in https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the hint!

Comment: There might be a $\otimes$ missing in the argument of the exponential

Comment: Thank you. That is absolutely right.